# How to embed image with overlay text CSS in Node js using `cid`

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, mean-stack

Being a newbie to Node, i need help in sending Mail with image embedded in node js.

Using `<img>` tag and `cid` I found that we can send an image embedded . But i also need some Text overlaid.

So, I found this could be done using CSS in the website [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp) but mail doesn't work with CSS.

How to link the `cid` when using CSS.

Below is the code i have at this point in time.

`

```
let mailOptions = {
      from: sender address, 
      to: list of receivers, 
      subject: Subject line,
      cc:requestedByEmail,      
html: '<div style="height: 100%;background-image: url("/images/hero-bg.jpg");background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;"><div style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);color: white;font-weight: bold;border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);z-index: 2;width: 80%;padding: 20px;text-align: center;"></div><h2>Blurred Background</h2>  <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>  <p>And I\'m a Photographer</p></div></img>',
      attachments: [{
        filename: 'hero-bg.jpg',
        path: __dirname+'/images/hero-bg.jpg',
        cid: 'hb' //same cid value as in the html img src
    }]
```

`

Is this the way to send out Email holding Images Embedded with CSS or any other way out there ?

Can someone help me in getting sorted this out.

Comment: which nodemailer npm you're using?

Comment: @MarciaOng It's Nodemailer I am using... `nodemailer = require('nodemailer');`

Comment: nodemailer@4.6.8